# Update and run pre defined link on current tab chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension go to a predefined link on the currently open tab. I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the background.js, Which handles the click event on extension.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, (tabs) => {
        const tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
            url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945425/update-and-run-pre-defined-link-on-current-tab-chrome-extension',
        });
    });
});
```

**Code Explanation**

1. On-click on the extension, I fetch the active tab information using `chrome.tabs.query` API.
2. `chrome.tabs.query` will return an array of tabs.
3. Get the 0'th indexed tab from the array and update the URL as per your requirement using `chrome.tabs.update` API.

**Reference**
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update