# Redirecting current tab to new url chrome extension (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, browser

Hey guys so I'm building an extension for chrome with VueJS and now I need to be able to when the user clicks a button in the extension it redirects the current tab to the new URL.

I tried the approach by this guy in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35523438

Unfortunately, it didn't work and I don't know if it's because of a bad implementation or simply wouldn't work anyways.

Here goes my code:

**ProductList.vue**

Ill only include the script part since its the important part. Its running BTW cuz when I click the button it prints out the url.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ProductList",
  props: {
    items: Array
  },
  methods: {
    shopProduct(url) {
      console.log(url);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage('open-product-url')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "homepage_url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "description": "A Vue Browser Extension",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "/app.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19.png",
      "38": "icons/38.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        console.log(sender.id);
        console.log(sender.tab.id);
        sendResponse(true);
    }
)
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    app: {
      template: 'public/app.html',
      entry: './src/main.js',
      title: 'App'
    }
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    browserExtension: {
      componentOptions: {
        background: {
          entry: './src/assets/js/background.js'
        },
        contentScripts: {
          entries: {
            'content-script': [
                './src/assets/js/contents.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For now, I only tried to print out the sender id since I want to later update the URL, and Ill need the sender tab id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem my self.

Docs I used to solve the issue: https://www.streaver.com/blog/posts/create-web-extension-vue.html

I was writing the listner in `background.js` when I should've wrote it in `contents.js` and in the vue component I needed to use a query and the send the message like the following:

```
browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }).then(tabs => {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
          msg: { action: "change_body_color", value: 'hey' }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This API of chrome, **Chrome.tabs.update**

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        console.log(sender.id);
        console.log(sender.tab.id);
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {
            url: '<new_url>',
        });
        sendResponse(true);
    }
)
```

Check this solution: [Update and run pre-defined link on current tab chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948433/10802524)

**Reference**
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update

**Suggestion**

- You don't need `"*://*/*"` permission if you are using `<all_urls>` permission.

Comment: Hey, tks for the help but the problem still exists where the background.js doesn't seem to be listening to the message cuz when I run it it doesn't do anything. Supposedly the background.js is working but I'm not sure how I can check it. I also added it to the manifest so should work.

Comment: Added a console.log to background and indeed its not printing anything so I suppose its not working? Do I need any permissions so the background works?

Comment: Fixed the problem